# imap - how to delete messages

Tags: python, imap

How can I delete messages from the mail box? I am using this code, but the letters are not removed. Sorry for my English.

```
def getimap(self,server,port,login,password):
    import imaplib, email
    box = imaplib.IMAP4(server,port)
    box.login(login,password)
    box.select()
    box.expunge()
    typ, data = box.search(None, 'ALL')
    for num in data[0].split() :
        typ, data = box.fetch(num, '(UID BODY[TEXT])')
        print num
        print data[0][1]
    box.close()
    box.logout()
```

Answer (score 40):

This is the working code for deleting all emails in your inbox:

```
import imaplib
box = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.mail.microsoftonline.com', 993)
box.login("user@domain.com","paswword")
box.select('Inbox')
typ, data = box.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
   box.store(num, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
box.expunge()
box.close()
box.logout()
```

Answer (score 24):

I think you should mark the emails to be deleted, first.. For example:

```
for num in data[0].split():
   box.store(num, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
box.expunge()
```

Answer (score 9):

This is what works for me, and it is really fast as I don't delete each email individually (store) but pass the list index instead. This works for gmail personal as well as enterprise (Google Apps for Business). It first selects the folder/label to use m.list() will show you all available. It then searches for emails over a year old, and performs a move to trash. It then flags all the emails in trash with the delete flag and expunges everything:

```
#!/bin/python

import datetime
import imaplib

m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")  # server to connect to
print "Connecting to mailbox..."
m.login('gmail@your_gmail.com', 'your_password')

print m.select('[Gmail]/All Mail')  # required to perform search, m.list() for all lables, '[Gmail]/Sent Mail'
before_date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(365)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")  # date string, 04-Jan-2013
typ, data = m.search(None, '(BEFORE {0})'.format(before_date))  # search pointer for msgs before before_date

if data != ['']:  # if not empty list means messages exist
    no_msgs = data[0].split()[-1]  # last msg id in the list
    print "To be removed:\t", no_msgs, "messages found with date before", before_date
    m.store("1:{0}".format(no_msgs), '+X-GM-LABELS', '\\Trash')  # move to trash
    print "Deleted {0} messages. Closing connection & logging out.".format(no_msgs)
else:
    print "Nothing to remove."

#This block empties trash, remove if you want to keep, Gmail auto purges trash after 30 days.
print("Emptying Trash & Expunge...")
m.select('[Gmail]/Trash')  # select all trash
m.store("1:*", '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')  #Flag all Trash as Deleted
m.expunge()  # not need if auto-expunge enabled

print("Done. Closing connection & logging out.")
m.close()
m.logout()
print "All Done."
```

Comment: I upvote for you bulk removal (which is indeed much faster if one wants to remove the whole mailbox).

Answer (score 8):

The following code prints some message header fields and then delete message.

```
import imaplib
from email.parser import HeaderParser
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("your_imap_server")
m.login("your_username","your_password")
# get list of mailboxes
list = m.list()
# select which mail box to process
m.select("Inbox") 
resp, data = m.uid('search',None, "ALL") # search and return Uids
uids = data[0].split()    
mailparser = HeaderParser()
for uid in uids:
    resp,data = m.uid('fetch',uid,"(BODY[HEADER])")        
    msg = mailparser.parsestr(data[0][1])       
    print (msg['From'],msg['Date'],msg['Subject'])        
    print m.uid('STORE',uid, '+FLAGS', '(\\Deleted)')
print m.expunge()
m.close() # close the mailbox
m.logout() # logout
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **GMail** the process is a bit different:

1. Move it to the [Gmail]/Trash folder.
2. Delete it from the [Gmail]/Trash folder (Add \Delete flag)

All emails in [Gmail]/Spam and [Gmail]/Trash are deleted after 30 days.
If you delete a message from [Gmail]/Spam or [Gmail]/Trash, it will be deleted permanently.

Remember also to call **EXPUNGE** after setting the tag Deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program I wrote, based on the code above:

https://github.com/AndrewDJohnson/py-purge-email/

```
import imaplib
import sys
import traceback
import datetime
import re
from getpass import getpass

"""
PyPurge Email V1.0
==================
Andrew Johnson
ad.johnson@ntlworld.com
06 Nov 2019


This Python 3 program will scan an email account using IMAP for messages older than
a certain age and delete them.

Old email can be deleted from all folders or each folder.

Because of the length of time bulikng deleting takes, folders can be scanned first
then the deletions can be left running (which might take several hours for many
thousands of messages.)

After running this, you may need to "empty" your deleted items/Trash folder to recover the space.
With hotmail/live/outlook accounts (i.e. online Microsoft ones) you will need to manually empty "recoverable items" too.
This is done within the "deleted items" folder when viewing your webmail.

"""

#You can hardcode your IMAP settings here, or they can be entered interactively.
#If "user" is set to a non-empty value, it is assumed the other values are set
#and so they are not requested  interactively.
host = ''
#Port 993 is normally the port for SSL comms for IMAP
port = 993
user=''
password = ''

#This is a list of the 3 most common email providers.
imap_hosts=[["GMail","imap.gmail.com","Trash"],
            ["Hotmail, Live, Outlook","imap-mail.outlook.com","Deleted"],
            ["Yahoo","imap.mail.yahoo.com","Trash"]]
#We default to checking for email that is older than 1 year.
days_old=365
deleted_mail_folder_name="Trash"



#This expression and function parse the mailbox data returned by the IMAP server
list_response_pattern = re.compile(r'\((?P<flags>.*?)\) "(?P<delimiter>.*)" (?P<name>.*)')
def parse_list_response(line):

    flags, delimiter, mailbox_name = list_response_pattern.match(line).groups()
    mailbox_name = mailbox_name.strip('"')
    if flags.lower().find("noselect") >= 0:
        mailbox_name=""  
    return (flags, delimiter, mailbox_name)

#This function will iterate through the folders on the IMAP server and check
#or delete email.
def do_folders(imap,days_old,check_or_del,deletion_list):
    #Confirm any deletion of emails.
    if check_or_del != "check":
        resp = input ("Are you sure you want to delete emails? (Enter 'Yes') to confirm)>>>")
        if resp.lower()!="yes":
            return

    #Get the folder list from the server
    resp, data = imap.list()
    totalMsgs = 0
    actioned= "Nothing to do!"
    if resp == 'OK':
        #Iterate through folders
        for mbox in data:
            flags, separator, name = parse_list_response(bytes.decode(mbox))
            #If mailbox name returned is empty, go to next entry.
            if name == "":
                continue
            # Select the mailbox for checking or deleting messages.
            print ("Checking folder: ",name)
            imap.select('"{0}"'.format(name), (check_or_del=="check"))

            #Search for messages older than the given date.
            before_date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days_old)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")  # date string, 
            resp, msgnums = imap.search(None, '(BEFORE {0})'.format(before_date))
            msg_count = len(msgnums[0].split())

            #Print the results
            print('{:<30} : {: d}'.format(name, msg_count))

            #Shall we check or delete?
            if (msg_count > 0):
                if (check_or_del=="check"):
                    #Ask the user if they want mail deleted from the folder found.
                    print ("Delete mail older than {0} in {1} folder? (Enter y to delete)>>> ".format(before_date, name))
                    resp=input("")

                    if resp.lower()=='y':
                        #Add the folder name to a list.
                        deletion_list.append (name)
                        totalMsgs = totalMsgs + msg_count

                    actioned="Total found to Delete:"
                    continue
                else:
                    actioned="Deleted: "
                    #Print a message telling the user about the time it might take!
                    if name in deletion_list or len(deletion_list) == 0:
                        totalMsgs = totalMsgs + msg_count                        
                        print (msg_count, "messages found with date before ", before_date, "will be moved to trash")
                        if (msg_count > 50000):
                            print ("This could take several hours!")
                        elif (msg_count > 5000):
                            print ("This could take an hour or more!")
                        elif (msg_count > 500):
                            print ("This could take a few minutes")

                        #Now mark the "found" messages as deleted using the IMAP library.    
                        imap.store("1:{0}".format(msg_count), '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted') 
                        continue
            else:
                #No messages found to delete so continue to next folder.
                continue

        print('{:<30} : {: d}'.format(actioned, totalMsgs))
        return (deletion_list)



folder = ''
deletion_list=[]


#Sign on message.
print ("*********--------****-----***************")
print ("* Python Email Purger - V1.0 - Nove 2019 *")
print ("*********--------****-----***************")
print (" ")

#Set some flags
exit_prog=False
input_needed=True

#Start a loop in case the user wants to have repeated runs of deleting messages!
while exit_prog==False:


    #Check if we already have some values from previous loop iteration
    if user != "":
        print ("Server:\t\t", host)
        print ("Username:\t",user)
        print ("Message Age:\t",days_old) 
        resp=input("Enter 'y' to use the values above>>> ")
        if resp != "y":
            user=""

    #Check if input values are already set and if they are not set,
    #read them in from the keyboard
    if user == "":
        while input_needed:
            #Get the host IMAP server domain etc.
            for i in range (0,len (imap_hosts)):
                print (i+1,imap_hosts[i][0], " - ",imap_hosts[i][1])
            input_needed=True            
            host_input=input("Enter imap server name number, as given above, or type the address>>> ")
            max_host_index=str(len(imap_hosts))
            if len (host_input)==1 and (host_input >"0") and (host_input <= max_host_index):
                host=imap_hosts[int(host_input)-1][1]
                #Set deleted items folder name.
                deleted_mail_folder_name=imap_hosts[int(host_input)-1][2]
                input_needed=False
            else:
                if len(host_input) < 10:
                    print ("Please enter a valid host address.")
                    input_needed=True
                else:
                    host=host_input
        user=input ("Username:")
        print ("Password:")
        #This is an attempt to read in the password without echo, but it
        #does not work when running in Windows GUI/IDLE
        password=getpass()

        #Get the required age of messages.
        input_needed=True
        while input_needed:
            input_needed=False
            resp = input("Deleted messages older than how many days? Default is '365'>>> ")
            if len (resp) > 0:
                days_old = int (resp)

            if days_old == 0:
                print ("You must enter a value greater than 0.")
                input_needed=True

    #Now connect to the server                              
    print ("Connecting to ",host,"...")
    imap = None

    try:
        # Create the IMAP Client
        imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host, port)
        # Login to the IMAP server
        resp, data = imap.login(user, password)
        #Check the server response.
        if resp == 'OK':
            print ("Logged in... Looking for messages older than", days_old, "days.")
            #Ask the user whether they want to delete messages in all folders, or
            #in selected folders.
            while not resp in ["c","a"]:
                resp = input ("Enter 'c' to check each folder, or 'a' to delete from all folders >>>")

            #Now call the function to check for and delete messages.
            if resp=="c":
                #Get folders and search for messages.
                deletion_list = do_folders(imap,days_old,"check", deletion_list)
                deletion_list = do_folders(imap,days_old,"delete", deletion_list)
            else:
                #Delete messages in selected folders
                deletion_list = do_folders(imap,days_old,"delete", deletion_list)

            if deleted_mail_folder_name!="":
                print("Emptying Trash & Expunge...")
                imap.select(deleted_mail_folder_name)  # select all trash
                imap.store("1:*", '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')  #Flag all Trash as Deleted
                imap.expunge() 
    except:
        resp = input ("Something went wrong... enter 'd' to see details, otherwise just press 'Enter' to exit...")
        if resp=='d':
            print('Error was : {0}'.format(sys.exc_info()[0]))
            traceback.print_exc()
            print ("Are you any the wiser? :-)")

#    finally:

        resp = input ("Enter 'Y' to delete more messages.")
        if resp.lower()!='y':
            exit_prog=True;
            if imap != None:
                imap.logout()
            imap = None
            print ("Finished...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

```
from imap_tools import MailBox 

# DELETE all messages from INBOX
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'password', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    mailbox.delete(mailbox.uids('ALL'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all emails from inbox.

```
## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#### Created by: James (Jamsey) P. Lopez
#### Created date: 11/28/2020
#### Modified date: 11/29/2020; 11/30/2020; 12/3/2020
## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
import win32com.client, time

#### Setting email
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
m = messages.GetFirst()

#### Loop for emails     
for m in list(messages):
    sender = m.SenderEmailAddress
    EmailDate = m.ReceivedTime
    if sender == "":
        m.Delete()
        time.sleep(.25)
    else:
        print sender
        print EmailDate
        m.Delete()
        time.sleep(.25)
```

Delete all emails with date condition.
This program will delete all emails older that 20 days from the current date.
Adjust the days in variable Dy in program. example. DY = 20

```
## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#### Created by: James (Jamsey) P. Lopez
#### Created date: 11/28/2020
#### Modified date: 11/29/2020; 11/30/2020; 12/3/2020
## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
import win32com.client, datetime, string, time
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

#### Setting email
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
m = messages.GetFirst()

############ The delete condition below
############ Creating the date that will determine which emails will be deleted
cur_date = datetime.today()

#### Days to keep and any emails older than 20 days will be deleted
#### Adjust the days to keep as needed
Dy = 20
datedays = cur_date-timedelta(days=Dy)
EndDy = "{}".format(datedays.strftime("%m/%d/%Y 00:00:00"))
EndDy = '"' + EndDy + '"'; ##print End30

#### Loop for emails     
for m in list(messages):
    sender = m.SenderEmailAddress

    EmailDate = m.ReceivedTime; ##print EmailDate
    EmailDate = datetime.strptime(str(EmailDate), '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'); ##print EmailDate
    EmailDate = EmailDate.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'); ##print EmailDate
    EmailDate = '"' + EmailDate + '"'; ##print EmailDate;print End30

    if sender == "":
        print EmailDate
        m.Delete()
        time.sleep(.25)
    elif EmailDate < EndDy:
        print ("\nDeleted email = %(sender)s and date = %(EmailDate)s" % vars())
        print ("          because it is older than %(EndDy)s" % vars())
        print ("          which is %(Dy)s days older than today %(cur_date)s\n" % vars())
        m.Delete()
        time.sleep(.25)
```

Comment: Please delete your second answer or merge them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the process workflow I use to either delete or keep emails in Outlook Inbox folder.
Managing emails is a constant maintenance issue.
Sometimes I have thousands of emails that I need to delete.
I have created two python programs which will enable me to efficiently manage this process workflow.

First - I write a python program to create a text and CSV file.
The text and CSV file contains two parts.

1. A count for each unique email.
2. The unique sender email address.

Second - I edit the text or CSV file to create two text files.

1. EmailsToKeep.txt.
   A. Emails I want to keep with no delete condition.
   B. I will manage these emails manually.
2. EmailsToKeepForAtLeast30Days.txt.
   A. Emails I want to keep or delete base on the date value of variable EndDy.
   I will append these two text files as needed.

Third - I write a second python program to delete or keep emails based on four conditions.

1. Delete emails that have no email address.
2. Keep emails that are in the EmailsToKeep.txt text file.
3. Keep or delete emails that are in the EmailsToKeepForAtLeast30Days.txt text file.
   A. Keep emails if date is newer than the date value of variable EndDy.
   B. Delete emails if date is older than the date value of variable EndDy.
4. Delete emails that were not included in any of the EmailsToKeep.txt or EmailsToKeepForAtLeast30Days.txt text files.
   Video link: https://youtu.be/bTgb3tO5r-8

   ```
    First python program.
    ## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Created by: James (Jamsey) P. Lopez
    ## Created date: 11/28/2020
    ## Modified date: 12/2/2020, 12/5/2020
    ## 
    #### This is the first python program of two
    #### Managing emails is a constant maintenance issue
    #### Sometimes I have thousands of emails that I need to delete
    #### This python programs will enable me to efficiently manage this process workflow
    ####
    #### I will create a dictionary of unique emails from the Inbox folder
    #### Then, create a for loop to create the TXT and CSV files
    #### I will edit the TXT or CSV file to create the final text files
    ####    The EmailsToKeep.txt and the EmailsToKeepForAtLeast30Days.txt
    ####        A. EmailsToKeep.txt is for emails I want to keep with no delete condition
    ####        B. EmailsToKeepForAtLeast30Days.txt is for emails that I want to keep based on the delete condition
    #### I will run this python program only once
    #### I will append these two text files as needed for the second python program
    ## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    import win32com.client, re, time, datetime, string

    ############################################################################################
    ############ Adding date to end of file name
    start_c = datetime.datetime.now(); ##print start_c
    c1 = (("%(start_c)s" % vars()).partition(' ')[0]); ##print c1
    new_str = string.replace(c1, '-', '_');new_str = "_"+new_str;##print(new_str)

    #### Path
    path = "S:\PythonProjects\EmailProject"
    Bslash = "\\"

    #### Text file
    EmailT = "EmailsTextFile"
    extt = ".txt"
    #### CSV file
    EmailC = "EmailsCSVFile"
    extc = ".csv"

    #### Full Text and CSV file name
    EmailTextFile = ("%(path)s%(Bslash)s%(EmailT)s%(new_str)s%(extt)s" % vars());print EmailTextFile
    EmailCSVFile = ("%(path)s%(Bslash)s%(EmailC)s%(new_str)s%(extc)s" % vars());print ("%(EmailCSVFile)s\n" %vars())

    #### Setting email
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    messages = inbox.Items
    messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
    m = messages.GetFirst()

    ############################################################################################
    ############ Create Text and CSV file if it does not exist or truncate if it does exist
    WriteEmailTextFile2=open('%(EmailTextFile)s' % vars(),'w')
    WriteEmailTextFile2.close()
    WriteEmailCSVFile2=open('%(EmailCSVFile)s' % vars(),'w')
    WriteEmailCSVFile2.close()

    #### Opening output Text and CSV files to append data
    WriteEmailTextFile=open('%(EmailTextFile)s' % vars(),'a')
    WriteEmailCSVFile=open('%(EmailCSVFile)s' % vars(),'a')

    #### Creating dictionary for all the emails in inbox
    #### This will create unique emails and how many times they are repeated
    d = dict()

    for m in messages:
        try:
            sender = m.SenderEmailAddress
            sender = sender.lower()
            if sender in d: 
                ## Increment count of emails by 1 
                d[sender] = d[sender] + 1
            else: 
                ## Add the emails to dictionary with count 1 
                d[sender] = 1
        except:
            pass

    #################################################
    #### Code to sort results in dictionary by sender email address
    from collections import OrderedDict 
    dict1 = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))

    #### For loop from sorted dictionary
    for key in dict1:
        #### d[key] contains the count for each unique sender email address
        #### key is the unique sender email address
        KeySelection = (d[key], key); ##print KeySelection
        #### Converting tuple to string so we can split
        KeySelection = str(KeySelection); ##print KeySelection

        #### Splitting the count and sender email address
        #### The split character = ,
        spl_char = ","
        ## Number of times the email sender is repeated
        EmailCount = KeySelection.rsplit(spl_char, 1)[0]
        ## Senders email name
        EmailName = KeySelection.rsplit(spl_char, 1)[-1]
        ##print s1; ##print s2

        ## Deleting characters and space/s
        ## All I need is the number of times (EmailCount) the sender email address is repeated
        ## and the senders email address (EmailName)
        EmailCount = re.sub(u"[(u') ]", '', EmailCount); ##print EmailCount
        EmailName = re.sub(u"[(u') ]", '', EmailName); ##print EmailName

        ## Writing line to TXT and CSV file
        line = ("%(EmailCount)s,%(EmailName)s\n" % vars())
        print line
        WriteEmailTextFile.write(line)
        WriteEmailCSVFile.write(line)
        ##time.sleep(2)

    #### Closing write files
    WriteEmailTextFile.close()
    WriteEmailCSVFile.close()



    Second python program.
    ## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #### Created by: James (Jamsey) P. Lopez
    #### Created date: 11/28/2020
    #### Modified date: 11/29/2020; 11/30/2020; 12/3/2020
    #### 
    #### This is the second python program of two
    #### Managing emails is a constant maintenance issue
    #### Sometimes I have thousands of emails that I need to delete
    #### This python programs will enable me to efficiently manage this process workflow
    ####
    #### This program uses two text files to accomplish my goal
    #### A. EmailsToKeep.txt is for emails I want to keep with no delete condition
    ####            I will manage these emails manually
    #### B. EmailsToKeepForAtLeast30Days.txt is for emails that I want to keep based on the delete condition
    ####            The delete condition is set to the variable End30
    #### I will append these two text files as needed
    ####
    #### Email maintenance conditions
    #### 1. Delete emails that have no email address
    #### 2. Keep emails that are in the EmailsToKeep.txt text file
    #### 3. Keep emails that are in the EmailsToKeepForAtLeast30Days.txt text file
    ####    A. Keep emails that are newer and equal to the value of variable End30
    ####    B. Delete the emails that are older than the value of variable End30
    #### 4. Delete emails that were not included in any of the EmailsToKeep.txt or EmailsToKeepForAtLeast30Days.txt text files
    ## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    import win32com.client, datetime, string, time
    from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

    ############################################################################################
    ############ Adding date to end of file name
    start_c = datetime.now(); ##print start_c
    c1 = (("%(start_c)s" % vars()).partition(' ')[0]); ##print c1
    new_str = string.replace(c1, '-', '_');new_str = "_"+new_str; ##print(new_str)

    #### Path
    path = "S:\PythonProjects\EmailProject"
    Bslash = "\\"

    #### Text file extension
    extt = ".txt"

    #### Existing text file of emails to keep
    EmailKTF = "EmailsToKeep"
    EmailKTFTextFile = ("%(path)s%(Bslash)s%(EmailKTF)s%(extt)s" % vars()); ##print EmailKTFTextFile

    #### Existing text file of emails used to delete specific emails after meeting delete condition
    TextFile30Day = "EmailsToKeepForAtLeast30Days"
    EmailTextFile30Day = ("%(path)s%(Bslash)s%(TextFile30Day)s%(extt)s" % vars()); ##print EmailTextFile30Day

    #### The delete text file
    EmailT = "EmailsDeletedTextFile"
    EmailTextFile = ("%(path)s%(Bslash)s%(EmailT)s%(new_str)s%(extt)s" % vars()); ##print EmailTextFile

    ############################################################################################
    ############ Create delete text file if it does not exist or truncate if it does exist
    WriteEmailTextFile2=open('%(EmailTextFile)s' % vars(),'w')
    WriteEmailTextFile2.close()

    #### Opening delete text files to write deleted emails
    WriteEmailTextFile=open('%(EmailTextFile)s' % vars(),'a')

    ############ The delete condition below
    ############ Creating the date that will determine which emails will be deleted
    cur_date = datetime.today()

    #### Days to keep
    Dy = 21
    datedays = cur_date-timedelta(days=Dy)
    EndDy = "{}".format(datedays.strftime("%m/%d/%Y 00:00:00"))
    EndDy = '"' + EndDy + '"'; ##print End30

    #### Counters
    TotalEmailsRead = 0
    TotalEmailInRead = 0
    TotalEmailsDeleted = 0

    #### Setting email
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    messages = inbox.Items
    messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
    m = messages.GetFirst()

    #### Loop for emails     
    for m in list(messages):
        TotalEmailsRead += 1

        EmailDate = m.ReceivedTime; ##print EmailDate
        EmailDate = datetime.strptime(str(EmailDate), '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'); ##print EmailDate
        EmailDate = EmailDate.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'); ##print EmailDate
        EmailDate = '"' + EmailDate + '"'; ##print EmailDate;print End30

        sender = m.SenderEmailAddress
        sender = sender.lower()

    ##    if sender == "alert@indeed.com" and EmailDate < End30:
    ##        print ("\n      AAAAAAA - Email = %(sender)s - Email Date = %(EmailDate)s - %(End30)s is the Cut off date" % vars())
    ##    print ("\n      BBBBBBB - %(EmailDate)s - %(End30)s - %(sender)s" % vars())

        KTF = open('%(EmailKTFTextFile)s' % vars(), 'r')
        TF30 = open('%(EmailTextFile30Day)s' % vars(), 'r')
        if sender == "":
            TotalEmailInRead += 1
    ##        print ("\n    1111  Deleted - Email sender is blank" % vars())
            line = ("No Sender : %(EmailDate)s\n" % vars())
            WriteEmailTextFile.write(line)
            m.Delete()
            TotalEmailsDeleted += 1
            time.sleep(.25)
        elif sender in KTF.read():
            TotalEmailInRead += 1
    ##        print ("\n2222 %(sender)s : %(EmailDate)s - IS IN %(EmailKTF)s text file" % vars())
            time.sleep(.25)
        elif sender in TF30.read():
            TotalEmailInRead += 1
    ##        print ("\n3333 %(sender)s : %(EmailDate)s - IS IN %(TextFile30Day)s text file" % vars())
            if EmailDate < EndDy:
    ##            print ("\n    4444 Deleted - %(sender)s : %(EmailDate)s : %(EndDy)s - IS IN %(TextFile30Day)s text file" % vars())
                line = ("%(sender)s : %(EmailDate)s : %(EndDy)s - IS IN email 30 day text file\n" % vars())
                WriteEmailTextFile.write(line)
                m.Delete()
                TotalEmailsDeleted += 1
                time.sleep(.25)
        else:
            TotalEmailInRead += 1
    ##        print ("\n    5555  Deleted - %(sender)s : %(EmailDate)s - IS NOT IN the %(EmailKTF)s and %(TextFile30Day)s text files" % vars())
            line = ("%(sender)s : %(EmailDate)s - IS NOT IN any of the read email text files\n" % vars())
            WriteEmailTextFile.write(line)
            m.Delete()
            TotalEmailsDeleted += 1
            time.sleep(.25)
        KTF.close()
        TF30.close()

    WriteEmailTextFile.close()

    print 'This is the total number of emails read from Outlook Inbox = ' + str(TotalEmailsRead)
    print 'This is the total number of emails processed in if statements = ' + str(TotalEmailInRead)
    print 'This is the total number of emails deleted in if statements = ' + str(TotalEmailsDeleted)
   ```